# gitattributes: Match two files with almost identical names, differing only in an additional fixed string

Tags: git, shell, smarty, wildcard, gitattributes

**Background**

When working with smarty templates, you can override files by creating a copy of a file and add the string *-USERMOD* to it, like this:

```
original_file.html
original_file-USERMOD.html
```

Is there a way to target *both* files in my .gitattributes file?

Just targeting the 2nd type of file is easy:

```
*-USERMOD* export-ignore
```

Literally speaking, the rule would be like this:
"If there is a copy of any file that ends in -USERMOD.original_extension, ignore both, the copy *and* the original"

I can always add those files manually of course, but an automated solution would be nice.

The man page for gitignore(5) (which is referred to by gitattributes(5) for explanation of pattern matching) says:

> Otherwise, Git treats the pattern as a shell glob suitable for consumption by fnmatch(3) with the FNM_PATHNAME flag

As far as I know, shell globs can't do what I need. The final goal however is to tell git to export-ignore USERMOD-files and their originals, thus any solution that solves this will be accepted.

Comment: Why not just write a makefile target for the archive and generate the attributes file then?  `make archive` is awfully easy to type.

Comment: @jthill Thx for the suggestion, but I'm currently not using _make_ in my project. I thought about creating the whole .gitattributes file, too, e.g. in a pre-commit hook, but it feels fragile, since I would have to specify some BOF / EOF for that specific -USERMOD section, so that I'm not overwriting manual changes as well. Or I would have to go with the [dotdee] (https://launchpad.net/dotdee) approach or similar strategies, which feels like taking a sledgehammer to crack a nut.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're going to have to script this somehow, I'd strongly recommend doing it as part of archive creation. Simplest might be

```
USERMOD-aware-archive() {
        git ls-files '*-USERMOD*' \
        | sed 's/$/ export-ignore/;p;s/-USERMOD//' >.git/info/attributes
        git archive "$@"
}
```

Comment: Tried this and like it so far, especially overwriting _.git/info/attributes_, since I'm not using this at all but only _.gitattributes_ and I don't have to worry about overwriting manual adjustments to _.gitattributes_ now, or do some crazy filtering. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: Btw, you need to add another / at the end of the sed script, else it will produce an error (editing it doesn't work because of the "at least 6 characters"-limitation when suggesting edits...)  
`...s/-USERMOD/' -> ...s/-USERMOD//'`

Answer (score 0):

In my experience:

```
original_file*.html
```

would do the trick, if you dont mind getting ignored files like:

> "original_file[withABunchOfStuffAroundHere].html"

Because of that,

```
*-USERMOD* export-ignore
```

may be a more specific pattern for your repo